# Hide HTML tags in the browser title bar

Tags: html, tags, hide

A client has asked me to customise their BigCartel site. 
I have made a product with a h tag in the title so that it shows up nicely on the page. However, the product name also pulls into the browser window title. the h tag is showing up in the title.

```
i.e. "title <h3>smalltitle</h3 / bigcartel.com "
```

Is there a way to hide html tags from the title with code without hiding them in the document?

Comment: There is no “h tag”. You have not specified what you mean by “the title”. Please provide a sample of valid HTML code and present the specific problem you are facing with it.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to "hide" tags in a `<title>`.

You should be using CSS to change the size of the *existing* product title, not an H-tag.

Answer (score 0):

Per Diodeus - you would have, in your page, something like:

```
<span class="smalltitle">title</span>
```

then your css would be:

```
.smalltitle {
  font-size:whatever;
  [some-other-attributes-here] 
}
```

then your title would simply be:

```
<title>title etc.</title>
```

Comment: in big cartel there is only an insert box for where the text should go. I want two different sized texts within this box but the only way I can see to do this is add span/title tags.. unfortunately there is some code pulling what I input into there, as a title.

If any one has experience with big cartel hopefully that made sense?!